# Mongo query returns empty array on initial run

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor

I have a collection named People that holds multiple documents. I am using Meteor JS for my website. When I run People.find({status: "Pending"}) it initially returns an empty array. If I wrap it in a [Tracker.autorun](http://docs.meteor.com/api/tracker.html#Tracker-autorun):

```
Tracker.autorun(function(){
   var peeps = People.find({status: "Pending"})
   Session.set('listo', peeps)
   console.log(peeps)
})
```

It finds the documents after first returning an empty array.

```
// => []
// => [{}]
```

The issue is that the first value (the empty array) is getting passed to my template and it is displaying none of the documents. I am using react for rendering:

```
  render() {
        
          return (
                  {
                    Session.get('listo').map((item) => {
                      HTML HERE
                    })
          )
  }
```

I thought that a session variable would work for this case but maybe this is conflicting with react or something, I'm not really sure.

To clarify the problem, the data always eventually gets loaded into the the *listo* session variable **but this new data is not displayed in the render() function**.

Comment: Your subscription to the `People` collection takes awhile to become ready - i.e. for collection data to be transferred from server to client. Best practice is to display a spinner until it does. Nothing to do with React.

Comment: The real problem is once the subscription ready and the Session variable gets updated, the new data doesn't get rendered in. It seems like react is just rendering the first value of Session.get('listo') which is sometimes empty.

Comment: You need to wrap your react component inside a reactive container. See https://guide.meteor.com/react.html#using-withTracker